# Is it possible to create a distance matrix in parts

Tags: qgis, postgis, pgrouting

Is it possible to create a distance matrix, using Pgrouting in parts? My computer doesn't complete the total nodes(crashes) , about 10.000 ....  I am looking for a way to use parts of the total number of nodes, to complete it later..

Comment: One of the [examples in the docs](http://docs.pgrouting.org/dev-tsp/en/src/fooDmatrix/doc/pgr_dijkstraDmatrix.html#pgr-dijkstradmatrix) is: `SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstraDmatrix(
    'SELECT id, source, target, cost, reverse_cost FROM edge_table',
    (SELECT array_agg(id) FROM edge_table_vertices_pgr WHERE id < 5),
    false
);` which means you are only using a subset of start vids. Or do you mean only building a subset of the edge table? If the latter, then you can do this, by, eg, using a spatial query to reduce the size of the edge table as the first parameter to pgr_dijkstraDmatrix.

Comment: I want to build a complete matrix. With the total number of 10.000 nodes, my computer crashes. On smaller number it finishes, but the point is to use all nodes.

Comment: Yes, that is understood. What isn't clear is if you are talking about using all the nodes in the input to the edge table (first paramter to function) or as the output, the 2nd parameter. There are multiple ways you could break the query into smaller sections and then combine the  results, but your question is not very clear.

Comment: I would like to use all the node from the input table, and combine them to get a complete result. So that in the end I have got all possibilities.. What would be a good way to achieve this with SQL?